# Java logging not logging for all classes?

Tags: java, logging

I am trying to do some logging in java(I am using the one provided by java itself not log4j), here is my code :

This is my **logger class**:

```
public class MyLogger {

    static MyFormatter formatter = null;
    static FileHandler fileHandler = null;
    static ConsoleHandler consoleHandler = null;
    static String preName = "";
    static Long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
    static String file_path = "/Users/rs/Documents/asl_v1/"+preName+time+".log";

    // setup method
    static public void setup() throws SecurityException, IOException {
        if(fileHandler == null)
            fileHandler = new FileHandler(file_path,true);
        if(consoleHandler == null)
            consoleHandler = new ConsoleHandler();
        if(formatter == null)
            formatter = new MyFormatter();  
        }

    static public Logger classLogger(String className){
        Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(className);
        logger.setUseParentHandlers(false);
        if(fileHandler == null || consoleHandler == null || formatter == null)
            try {
                setup();
                fileHandler.setFormatter(formatter);
                consoleHandler.setFormatter(formatter);
                Handler[] handlers = logger.getHandlers();
                // array of registered handlers
                for (int i = 0; i < handlers.length; i++)
                    logger.removeHandler(handlers[i]);

                logger.setLevel(Level.INFO);
                logger.addHandler(fileHandler);

            } catch (SecurityException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        return logger;
    }

    static public Logger classLogger(String className,
            String log_prefix) {
        preName = log_prefix;
        file_path = "/Users/rs/Documents/asl_v1/"+preName+time+".log";
        return classLogger(className);
    }
```

This is my **formatter class**:

```
public class MyFormatter extends Formatter {

    @Override
    public String format(LogRecord record) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        StringBuilder r = new StringBuilder();
        r.append("<")
            .append(record.getMillis())
            .append(">")
            .append(" ")
            .append(record.getSourceClassName())
            .append(" ")
            .append(record.getSourceMethodName())
            .append(" ")
            .append(record.getThreadID())
            .append(" ")
            .append(record.getLevel())
            .append(" ")
            .append(record.getMessage())
            .append(System
            .getProperty("line.separator"));

            return r.toString();
    }



}
```

I have added the following in my code in **class MakeClient** :

```
public final static Logger logger = MyLogger.classLogger(MakeClientsClass.class.getName(),"client-");
logger.info("Beginning experiment");
```

And this code in **ClientInstance**:

```
public final static Logger logger = MyLogger.classLogger(ClientThreadInstance.class.getName());
logger.info("Client with id ::"+client_id);
```

The log file for MakeClient appears just fine, but the file for ClientInstance doesnt appear(I tought the data would be logged in the same file,even that does not happen)

I tried to log it in a totally separate file i did:

```
  public final static Logger logger = MyLogger.classLogger(ClientThreadInstance.class.getName(),"client-instance");
    logger.info("Client with id ::"+client_id);
```

But there is no file appearing at all! ***So the logger works for the MakeClient class but not for the other class!!***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the corrected version of your MyLogger class. Please see below.

```
public class MyLogger {

    static MyFormatter formatter = null;
    static FileHandler fileHandler = null;
    static ConsoleHandler consoleHandler = null;
    static String preName = "";
    static Long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
    static String file_path = "/Users/rs/Documents/asl_v1/" + preName + time + ".log";

    // setup method
    static public void setup() throws SecurityException, IOException {
        /*if (fileHandler == null)*/
            fileHandler = new FileHandler(file_path, true);
        if (consoleHandler == null)
            consoleHandler = new ConsoleHandler();
        if (formatter == null)
            formatter = new MyFormatter();
    }

    static public Logger classLogger(String className) {
        Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(className);
        logger.setUseParentHandlers(false);
        /*if (fileHandler == null || consoleHandler == null || formatter == null)*/    
            try {
                setup();
                fileHandler.setFormatter(formatter);

                consoleHandler.setFormatter(formatter);
                Handler[] handlers = logger.getHandlers();

                // array of registered handlers
                for (Handler handler : handlers) {
                   logger.removeHandler(handler);
                }

                logger.setLevel(Level.INFO);
                logger.addHandler(fileHandler);
            } catch (SecurityException | IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        return logger;
    }

    static public Logger classLogger(String className, String log_prefix) {
        preName = log_prefix;
        file_path = "/Users/rs/Documents/asl_v1/" + preName + time + ".log";
        return classLogger(className);
    }
}
```

If you see in here, you are loading the same FileHandler for all of your classes and therefore when you run your application it worked only one instance of FileHandler. Now file handler not null check is commented in setup() method and also first if check is commented it out from parameterized classLogger method since setup() method has relevant checks, so no need to duplicate them. Still it requires a bit effort to make changes in your logger class, like if the path is the same with the old one, then use existing FileHandler, etc..

Please consider using Factory design pattern in your logging which makes your code robust, smooth and maintainable. Now it is too messy.

Comment: Thank you, I tried to run it again but seem to be getting the same problem, you see my first class generates threads instances of the second class ie MakeClient makes several threads of ClientInstance object, could that have anything to do with this?

Comment: I tried to even change the file name,but it seems the log file does not get generated, even tought i place both in the same folder.

Comment: It is really hard to say something without seeing your code. Can you share your MakeClient and ClientInstance classes?

Comment: Please post your ClientInstance class as well, otherwise I cannot compile the other two.

Comment: its part of a huge project.

Comment: I found the problem and posted revised MyLogger class in an answer. Please check it and if it works, accept the answer.