# How to reduce the frequency of logging in Java?

Tags: java, logging

I am using java logging(the one provided by default)in the java environment.

I wanted to ask how I could aggregate my readings and log lets say once every second instead of more often(I seem to be logging 20 times a second).
How can that be done?

Is there any setting that I can use where it pushes data to file less often?
I have never logged before so I am not sure if it is possible.Thank you.

EDIT: I am logging response time, throughput and stuff like that. Since my program is heavy I want jul to buffer and log less often.

Comment: I would say you don't need to do this because the logging framework should be buffering. I saw this documented for log4j, so I assume jul does the same.

Comment: What kind of logging? logging to a file for the behavior of the program? or logging to follow to debug your program like "System.out..."?

Comment: program measurements.

Comment: With performance measurements your best option is probably not to log them at all. Collect and aggregate the data and expose it through JMX.

Comment: @LoveMeow Side note: never "answer" questions from comments in another comments. Always update your question instead!

Comment: I also wrote it in my question. throughput,response time = program measurements, sry if I wasnt clear

Comment: @biziclop how would I do that?

Comment: @LoveMeow [Here's](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jmx/mbeans/standard.html) the tutorial for creating `MBean`s, which are then handled by JMX.

Comment: Is it an external tool? because we are not allowed to use external tool except for those provided by core java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To customize logging with [JUL](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/logging/package-summary.html) you can write your own [Handler](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/logging/Handler.html) implementation. If you want to log to a file you should extend [FileHandler](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/logging/FileHandler.html). An implementation using [ConsoleHandler](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/logging/ConsoleHandler.html) could look like this:

```
package my.logging;

import java.util.Queue;
import java.util.concurrent.*;
import java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler;
import java.util.logging.LogRecord;

public class BufferingHandler extends ConsoleHandler implements AutoCloseable {

    private final Queue<LogRecord> logRecordsFifo = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<>();
    private final ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();

    public BufferingHandler(final int delay, final TimeUnit timeUnit) {
        super();
        scheduler.scheduleWithFixedDelay(() -> handleLogs(), delay, delay, timeUnit);
    }

    private void handleLogs() {
        while (!logRecordsFifo.isEmpty()) {
            // sync is required to preserve logs order when flushing
            synchronized (logRecordsFifo) { 
                final LogRecord log = logRecordsFifo.poll();
                if (log != null) super.publish(log);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void publish(final LogRecord record) {
        if (!isLoggable(record)) return;
        logRecordsFifo.add(record);
    }

    @Override
    public void flush() {
        handleLogs();
        super.flush();
    }

    @Override
    public void close() {
        scheduler.shutdown();
        flush();
        super.close();
    }
}
```

Usage of this handler could look like this:

```
import my.logging.BufferingHandler;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(App.class.getName());
        try (final BufferingHandler bufferingHandler = new BufferingHandler(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)) {
            logger.addHandler(bufferingHandler);
            for (int i = 0; i < 30; ++i) {
                Thread.sleep(200);
                logger.info("some info: " + i);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Do I have to have thread sleep before loggin my emasurements as well? or is it enough to specify the time in the bufferingHandler

Comment: You don't, it is just an example to show that it does write the aggregated logs out every second. Yes it is enough to specify the time in the BufferingHandler constructor.

Comment: @LoveMeow Does it answer your question?

Comment: I am implementing it right now,once it works ill let you know.Yes it answers my question! :)

Comment: I am having a few problems, in my case I have class 1 that spawns many threads of class 2, class 1 logs fine, class 2 does not log at all(no file even created), also I dont know if auto closable is working,because my programs seems to never end,after its done it feel like it waiting for something.

Comment: @LoveMeow `AutoCloseable` means that you can use it with [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) block. If you don't use it with try-with-resources block you need to call `close` explicitly. `ScheduledExecutorService` once used creates a thread which needs to be closed before your program exits. It is hard to address your problems without the code.

Comment: I did that and it closes! But I still find that my log files are not logging,you see I have made a custom logger and formatter class like the one here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33068297/java-logging-not-logging-for-all-classes I am not sure how to fit this bufferinghandler with the existing filehandler there. I tried replacing it but that dint work either.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92591/discussion-between-marcin-krol-and-lovemeow).